# Using CSS tricks full width on mobile phones

Tags: iphone, css, mobile

Is there anyway to apply this method from Chris Coyier to mobile phones: http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/

I applied

```
html {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

To get rid of the horizontal scrollbar, but when viewing on an iphone for instance. There is a horizontal scrollbar.

You can view the site here: http://www.revival.tv/turningpoint/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding it to the body tag, too.

body {overflow-x: hidden;}

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` within the head tag of your page.

Comment: Thanks, I already have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Find the the thing that's causing the scrollbar and get rid of it. Hiding overflow-x seems a bit of a sticking plaster to me - if you do it right in the first place you shouldn't need this. Using media queries allow you to set the width of the page at difference screen sizes. This means you can pretty much wrap you content in div and set its width at the different screen sizes

Comment: Well I'm using Chris Coyier's method to add full width bars to my page which requires the x overflow to be hidden. This can be hidden using ShogunArts method above by adding {overflow-x: hidden;} to the body.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding that the initial-scale attribute is crashing Safari for a web page that contains an embedded Google Map. http://w.pat.tc

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

Thats usefull for my moblie web http://www.sepatuonline-murah.com